# jQuery UI sortable not working properly

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

My problem is somewhat strange.
I have a droppable combined with a sortable.
When the sortable is empty and then I drop elements in there and try to sort them, the sorting is not working properly. The placeholder often does not change the position correctly. [Look here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tsj5eu3m/2/)

But! (and thats strange) When I populate the sortable directly in HTML the sorting works great! It's smooth and reacts correcty. [Look here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tsj5eu3m/3/)

In both versions the LI-elements in the sortable are the same!
I don't know what's wrong, lost already some hours on this...
Has anybody an idea?

Edit:

Javascript-Code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#ipk li" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $( "#display ul" ).droppable({
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( '<li></li>' ).addClass('ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle').text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        }
    });
    $( "#display ul" ).sortable();
    $( "#display ul" ).disableSelection();
});
```

CSS:

```
#display { width: 800px; height: 250px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ebebeb; }
#display ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 850px; height: 200px; }
#display li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 25px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ebebeb; }
```

HTML with problems:

```
<div id="ipk">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">IPKs</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Orange</li>
        <li>Banana</li>
        <li>Onion</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="display">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Display</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML without problems:

```
<div id="ipk">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">IPKs</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Orange</li>
        <li>Banana</li>
        <li>Onion</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="display">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Display</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">Apple</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">Orange</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">Banana</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">Onion</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code to your question. Fiddles are nice, but some context to go with them is even better.